# Join Table in python Pandas (like Vlookup based on two columns value similarity)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

it should be easy but I don't find the solution.
I want to join two data frames using pandas, joined like V loop Up style when comparing values of two columns from two data frames.
See example

```
 df1_test =  pd.DataFrame({'X_mm': [1,2,3,4,5],
                               'Y_mm': [2,5,6,7,9],
                               "Measurement_from_df1":[18.3,19.3,20.25,10.3,20.1]
                                })


df2_test =  pd.DataFrame({'X_mm': [1,2,0,6,12],
                               'Y_mm': [2,5,18,24,37],
                               "Measurement_from_df2":[20,25,31,32,33]
                                })

result = pd.DataFrame({'X_mm': [1,2],
                               'Y_mm': [2,5],
                       "Measurement_from_df1":[18.3,19.3],                       
                               "Measurement_from_df2":[20,25]
                                })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
print(df1_test.merge(df2_test, on=["X_mm", "Y_mm"]))
```

Prints:

```
   X_mm  Y_mm  Measurement_from_df1  Measurement_from_df2
0     1     2                  18.3                    20
1     2     5                  19.3                    25
```